# adding a file to an embedded class in play morphia

Tags: playframework, morphia

I have an embedded class that has a Blob member. Calling fromJson on the document results in a session timeout. What should happen here?

```
Model > Embedded > Blob
```

My guess is there is a bug somewhere in here and I need to design around it.

Comment: If you think there is a bug, submit an issue report to http://github.com/greenlaw110/play-morphia/issues. It would be even better you clone the project and add a test case in samples-and-tests/unit-tests project

Comment: I built a sample project to show the problem and it worked which is cool, but now I am trying to see why. Certainly doing List<Blob> does bad things to the compiler - is that even supported?

Comment: List<Blob> is not supported. What you can do is to define a Resource model which contains only one Blob fields, and in your original model create a list of that resource model

Comment: I found this link. It appears to be closer to what I am looking for. Is that what you meant by a resource model? https://gist.github.com/1275419   I am looking at the direct GridFS calls mostly.

Comment: actually this is what I mean: https://gist.github.com/2947784

Comment: I am trying to avoid a collection (docs) pointing to a collection (blobs) pointing to a collection (files). It seems direct access to GridFS is fairly basic to do.